# How to Use defined Object instead of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, dry, fluentvalidation

I have few Model Classes and I noticed the `Name` property (eg: *CountryName, BranchName, StateName,* etc) has the same rule across the application, like it must be mandatory and cannot exceed certain number of characters. In the following example of `BranchAddClass.cs`.

---

**Question:**

---

1. How to define the custom object and re-use in the `Model Class` code instead of declaring as string (see the `BranchName` property in `BranchAddModel.cs`).
2. How to implement the `FluentValidation` rules within **NameField.cs**. At the moment, the validation is being repeated (see `BranchAddModel.cs` class).

**NameField.cs**

I was thinking to create an object class and perform the validation in this class, so that I don't break the `DRY` principle. But am unable to achieve it. If you have a better way to implement what am trying to achieve would be welcomed!

```
public class NameField
    {
        private readonly string _value;

        private NameField(string value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
```

If the NameField class works then am hoping that I could use that in the rest of the application, see the example

**BranchAddModel.cs**

```
namespace Application
{
    [Validator(typeof(BranchAddModelValidator))]
    public class BranchAddModel
    {
        public byte ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }  //this could be replaced when NameField issue is solved.
        public NameField PreferredBranchName { get; set; }   //Reference to NameField class
        public short BaseCurrencyId { get; set; }
        public short TimezoneId { get; set; }
    }

    public class BranchAddModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchAddModel>
    {
        public BranchAddModelValidator()
        {
            //trying to avoid writing this validation.
            RuleFor(x => x.BranchName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .Length(0, 128);

            RuleFor(x => x.ServiceTypeId)
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.BaseCurrencyId)
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.TimezoneId)
                .NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If you think the question is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Use reflection to build up an expression tree to pass into `RuleFor`

Comment: @Rob Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use generics. This way you can easily add it to other models and properties (CountryName, StateName).

```
public class BranchAddModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchAddModel>
{
    public BranchAddModelValidator()
    {
        this.AddDefaultNameValidation(x => x.BranchName);

        RuleFor(x => x.ServiceTypeId)
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.BaseCurrencyId)
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.TimezoneId)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}

public static class AbstractValidatorExtensions
{
    public static void AddDefaultNameValidation<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator, Expression<Func<T, string>> property)
    {
        validator.RuleFor(property)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(0, 128);
    }
}
```

NOTE: It compiles, but I didn't test if the validation actually works. Fluent Validation package is new for me and I don't have time now to investigate it, but looks worth to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping the class, you can do something like this:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BranchAddModel));
var items = typeof(BranchAddModel).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    .Select(r => Expression.Lambda<Func<BranchAddModel, string>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, r.Name), param));

foreach (var item in items)
{
    RuleFor(item)
        .NotEmpty()
        .Length(0, 128);
}
```

Which will build an enumerable of `Expression<Func<BranchAddModel, string>>` which you can then loop through and pass to `RuleFor`